# Input box does not show default value

Tags: jquery, html

I have an email box in which I like to show a default value with "enter your email"

Herefore I created an email box in HTML:

```
<p> Email: <br /> <input type="email" size="30"/> </p>
```

An the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var default = "Please enter your email adress;

    $("input").attr("value", default);
});
```

It does not show up however. Anybody suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing a double quote

Answer (score 7):

why are you doing this, you can directly use `placeholder` attribute.

there is no need of using jquery or javascript

```
 <p> Email: <br /> <input type="email" size="30" placeholder="please enter your email address"/> </p>
```

Comment: Though this is a more logical approach, it's probably worth noting that this will not work on IE8 or 9.

Answer (score 3):

Two things: Firstly, `default` is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) in JavaScript so may not be used as a variable name. Change this to something else (e.g. `defaultString`):

```
var defaultString = ...;
```

Secondly you're missing the closing `"` on your assignment string:

```
var defaultString = "Please enter your email adress;
                                             ^
```

Also you should use `val()` for values, not `attr()`:

```
$("input").val(defaultString);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use jquery water mark:

```
$('#myElement').watermark('Enter your email');
```

Please see jsfiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/NMtfK/

Comment: What is that? At least provide plugin link

Comment: Please see my answer again I add a jsfiddle example link.

Answer (score 2):

Try like,

```
$("input").val(default);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `default` as variable name:  [SEE WHY?](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sdefault = "Please enter your email adress";

    $("input").attr("value", sdefault);
});
```

But you should use instead:

```
$("input").val(sdefault);
```

Or better use placeholder attribute on modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use placeholder attribute

```
 <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address"/>
```

**Note:** The approach you are following is not good because when you will focus on input box then you have to clear all the default text. So use placeholder which is ment for same purpose.